# Does add attribute to close tag has any side effect on any browser?

Tags: html

I found that add attribute to close tag can treat as comment and is very convenient:

`<div id="container">
    very many mess that you may mess up tags....
</div container end>`

And tested it on every browser and it seems no quirk.

I want to know does it has any side effect that I didn't notice?

Comment: @codehorse I think he means like: `<div></div class='end'>`

Comment: **End tags must have no attributes.** (if you meant it). Although HTML5 allows you to write flexible HTML pages but HTML still restricts no attributes allowed in end tags.

Answer (score 3):

It makes your html not valid anymore. It may have unexpected side effects, like forcing IE into "quirks" mode. Also, it seems abusive. **Please** just use HTML comments, `<!-- Hello, World! -->`.

Comment: Can you cite a documentation of an observed side effect? It does not sound plausible that the construct would affect IE’s mode (which is determined in a messy way, but I have never seen any reference to end tag syntax affecting it).

Answer (score 0):

In “genuine” XHTML, i.e. XHTML served with an XML content type, an attribute in an end tag is treated as a well-formedness error: the page is not displayed at all, and an error message is displayed instead.

Otherwise, there are no documented effects. The [parsing rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing) in the current HTML5 CR imply that attributes in an end tag are parsed, but no processing (no meaning) is assigned to them. They are not specified as causing a parse error. This may, however, be an oversight; but declaring them as parse errors would just mean that browsers “may abort the parser” (and browsers do not actually do such things).

Thus, in HTML syntax (as opposite to XHTML syntax), attributes in end tags can be expected to be ignored. On the other hand, there is nothing particularly convenient about them. If you use `</div container end>`, it may have undesired side effects on *you* or other humans that read the HTML source. You may get lured into thinking that this must be an end tag for `<div id="container">`. It may, or it may not; this simply depends on whether it actually matches in the syntax – something that a good editor should show you.